# Getting header resend error in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, pug, url-routing

I have following routing:

```
router.get('/blog/:title', function (req, res) {
        blog.getBlogPost(req, function (data) {
            res.render('blog', data);
        });
    });
```

and the function `getBlogPost`

```
exports.getBlogPost = function (req, callback) {

// TODO SAFE PARAM
// TODO ERR Handling

var title = req.param('title');
Blog.findOne({permaLink: title}).exec(function (err, data) {

    var date = new Date(+data.timestamp);
    data.tags = createHashtagsFromCSV(data.tags);
    data.date = month_names_long[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getDate() + ", " + date.getFullYear();

    callback(data);
});
// not found
callback({});
};
```

and strangely I get following Node console log

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:689:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\qcode\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:662:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\qcode\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:146:12)
    at fn (C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\qcode\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:896:10)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\qcode\node_modules\jade\lib\jade.js:325:12)
    at View.render (C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\qcode\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:76:8)
    at Function.app.render (C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\qcode\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:527:10)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\qcode\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:900:7)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\qcode\app.js:65:9)
    at Layer.handle_error (C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\qcode\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:58:5)
```

I have done stuff like this already a few times in my project, but this times it throws this error and I have now clue why? Any idea why?

Comment: Any middleware was added?

Comment: Nope, changed nothing what could produce this

Comment: Your callback calls twice. So the second one throw header error

Comment: oh yeah, what a douche mistake and I didn't saw it. Thanks

Comment: Now everything works fine :p thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback calls twice. So the second one throw header error

Make something like

```
Blog.findOne({permaLink: title}).exec(function (err, data) {

    if (!data) {
       callback({});
       return;
    }

    var date = new Date(+data.timestamp);
    data.tags = createHashtagsFromCSV(data.tags);
    data.date = month_names_long[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getDate() + ", " + date.getFullYear();

    callback(data);
});
```